# related items on same table

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, self-join

I have a table with supplier details:

```
id  |name      |website           |phone        |image    |related to id|
 1  |mike      |www.example.com   |212-555-555  |img/1.jpg|    2        |
 2  |bill      |www.example.net   |212-666-666  |img/2.jpg|    1        |
```

my query:

```
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query); 
    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supplier
    WHERE (`id` LIKE '".$query."')") or die(mysql_error());  
    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){  
        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

                 echo $results['name'] ...['phone']  // just an example

        }
```

so if q=1 i will get mike's details.

but what if i want to show also related id details?

for example : if bill is related to mike , how can i show bill's details on          page when q=1?

*i know this is not best practice it's just to demonstrate my problem

Comment: Can you post expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try inner join

```
 $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT a.name as Member,b.name as RelatedMember 
 FROM suppliers a
 INNER JOIN suppliers b ON a.id= b.related_to_id WHERE (`a`.`id` = '".$id."')
 ORDER BY Member");
```